# is there a qualifier to indicate a C pointer as 'given to you and should be freed by you'?

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a C project and need implement some functions, for some of them I need to return a pointer and rely on the caller to `free()` it, and for some I just lend the pointer to him.

Is there a qualifier in C preceeding the pointer to show the convention, like:

```
  you_free_it   char *foo();
  just_lend_you char *foo2();
```

And when I am a caller, I also want to qualify my pointer variable which receives the result for safer operation. like:

```
  you_free_it   char *ptr  = foo();
  just_lend_you char *ptr2 = foo2();
```

Comment: Nope. You have to keep track of it yourself. C++ has `unique_ptr` which will automatically call the destructor when it goes out of scope.

Comment: The answer is indeed 'no'. It has been the frustration of a lot of programmers actually. C++ does a much better job with references and smart pointers, but when passed a raw pointer you still have to look it up. One could work around the problem in C using special variable prefixes or a macro that expands to nothingness (e.g. void * __transfer_ownership arg)

Comment: You should also ask yourself about the lifetime of an object. If not handled properly, the code will be swarmed with dangling references. Even C++ suffers from this. That's why nowadays I am teaching myself the Rust programming language.

Comment: No, but passing a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) by reference comes close to `just_lend_you` in C++.

Comment: This is a perfect example of how "C doesn't come with training-wheels", it is up to you as the programmer to factor your code to always (1) know the type of pointer being used, and (2) for pointers to allocated types, preserve a pointer to the starting address of the block, so (3) it can be freed when it is no longer needed.

Comment: For strings, you typically mark return values that shouldn't be freed as `const char *`.

Comment: Plain C pointers do not have any metadata associated with them about storage class, ownership, or anything else.  You could create a `struct` type that wraps a pointer along with some metadata, but it rapidly becomes a pain to maintain.  You have to design and document your code accordingly.

Comment: I name my allocating constructor functions with a `__new` at the end, e.g., `foo__new` (you may want to use just one `_` for C++ compatibility). That way I can see from the name that the returned object should be free'd or deconstructed-and-free'd somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually return a struct:

```
struct resourceptr {
    void *p;
};

char *dont_free_me();
struct resourceptr free_me();
```

`struct resourceptr` will be exactly as big as a pointer, but it's very clear that it's different from a normal pointer. (`void *` will implicitly convert to anything though...)

A few points:

- If you have an interface which returns an allocated resource, provide a function to free that resource. In this example, don't ask the caller to call `free()`, provide a specific function that they have to call, which will call `free()`. Otherwise you're leaking implementation details through your abstraction.
- Your question is also tagged with "C++". If you're in C++, then:
- Use `new` and `delete` not `malloc()` and `free()`.
- You can just return an rvalue reference to an `std::string`, IIRC.
- There are ways to implement classes that are reference-counted, does not incur extra memory allocations, and implicitly convert to `char *` and/or `std::string`.
- Like @doug said, there's `unique_ptr` - that incurs another memory allocation though, in case you care about that.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the comments, there is no "canonical" way to do this in C. But if you need to communicate ownership of a resource explicitly (i.e. not just though documentation which explains to users of your library which resources must be `free`'d), I would suggest one possible approach:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USER_MUST_FREE(res) ( (res->type) == USER_FREE ? 1 : 0 )

enum RES_TYPE { API_FREE, USER_FREE }; /* type of resource */

struct res_ptr {
    enum RES_TYPE type;
    void *ptr;      /* the actual resources, could be any type */
    /* could hold a function pointer to a custom `free' function */
};

typedef union {
    enum RES_TYPE type;
    struct res_ptr *res;
    /* could hold other types of resources, too */
} my_resource;

int main(void)
{
    my_resource *resource;

    resource = some_resource_generator(); /* function omitted for simplicity */

    /* do something with the resource */

    if (USER_MUST_FREE(resource)) {
        free(resource->res->ptr);
        free(resource->res);
        free(resource);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, a union `my_resource` holds information about whether a resource should be `free`'d by the user or if `free`ing is handled by the library's API automatically. In a larger-scale application, one could push all resources on a dedicated stack and when cleaning up, loop over that stack, asking every resources if it needs to be deallocated. I used this pattern before and with some utility functions/a nicer API it worked well for me!

Comment: It may have worked well for you, but it is not standard C.   The `USER_MUST_FREE` macro and its usage relies on a non-standard (gnu compiler specific) extension.

Comment: Oh well, that macro is obviously not the code pattern here. I'll remove it!

Comment: In which case would it be beneficial to expose those details to caller? I would just add `some_resource_free` function and let it do all necessary cleanup.

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo agreed! I wanted to demonstrate a possible implementation as clearly as possible. But as I wrote, an appropriate API/some utility functions are easy to implement and abstract away individual `free` calls.